# String ('yyyyMMddHHmmss') to date format with Kendogrid using columns.Bound

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

From the backend I am receiving a string with the format of "yyyyMMddHHmmss".  When it displays in the kendo grid I need it to have the format of "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss".

I am working in an MVC model and have tried to change the date as we get them from the back end but when we run an update the row updated is in the wrong format.

I have tried :

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.UploadDate).Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}");
```

which does not format the date.

I have also tried to variations of the following

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UploadDate).ClientTemplate("#=UploadDate ? kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(UploadDate,yyyyMMddHHmmss), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#");
```

and

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UploadDate).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(UploadDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#");
```

Both of those create an "Invalid template" error on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Format()` function will only work if `UploadDate` is a `DateTime` object on your model:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UploadDate).Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}");
```

Your first ClientTemplate example fails because you are using an inline shorthand if statement, but are missing the false part ":" (see the client template solution below).

I believe your second ClientTemplate example fails because "yyyyMMddHHmmss" is not a standard date format and therefore the `kendo.dateParse()` function fails.

Using a ClientTemplate is what you will have to do if you cannot convert the field to a DateTime in the Model.  Try this:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UploadDate)
       .ClientTemplate("#= UploadDate 
                       ? kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(UploadDate, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
                       : '' #");
```

References:

- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateparsing
- http://www.telerik.com/forums/datetime-format-on-grid-cells-date(-)-#RI6E1Tvk30ye1iW9nmhlyw